# Cast a Byte variable and convert it to String

Tags: java, string, byte

I want to Print in console the value of a Byte variable.
I created the Class "Portata""

```
public class Portata {
    String nome,descr,portata;

    double prezzo;
    byte qt,cottura;
    String[] ingr,allerg;


    public Portata(String nome, String descr, String[] ingr, String[] allerg, double prezzo, byte cottura, String portata, byte qt) {
        this.nome=nome;
        this.descr=descr;
        this.ingr=ingr;
        this.allerg=allerg;
        this.prezzo=prezzo;
        this.portata=portata;
        this.qt=qt;
    }

   /** All getters and setters **/

    public byte getCottura() {
        return cottura;
    }

    public byte getQt() {
        return qt;
    }

 /** All getters and setters **/
}
```

I created an ArrayList in another class:

```
 ArrayList<Portata> piatti=(new Portata("Pasta al Sugo","Ottimo piatto di pasta al Sugo",elenco_ingredienti,elenco_allergeni,25.00,(byte)15,"Primo",(byte)0));
```

But when I try:

```
  System.out.println(piatti.get(0).getNome()+", "+piatti.get(0).getDescr()+", "+Byte.toString(piatti.get(0).getCottura())+" ");
```

It shows up as:

```
 "Pasta al Sugo, Ottimo piatto di pasta al Sugo, 0"
```

How can I show the Byte value **(15)** instead of **0** ?

Comment: * elenco_ingredienti,elenco_allergeni are two Arrays containing multiple strings. No problems with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't initialize the `cottura` field in the constructor nor with a setter hence it will always remain `0` as that's the default value of a `byte`.

To fix the issue, initialize the `cottura` field in the constructor as follows:

```
this.cottura = cottura;
```

Comment: Thank you! Really didn't see that.